# Uncoverable code lines and SonarQube (in C)

Tags: c, sonarqube, code-coverage

We are using SonarQube with our C project, and code coverage is reporting low values in some parts of the code which typically look like:

```
if (hell_freezes_over()) {
    // something ...
}
```

For instance:

```
    char buf[BIG_BUFFER];
    n = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/foo/%d", fd);
    if (n >= sizeof(buf)) {
        errno = ENOSPC;
        return -1;
    }
```

That `if(...)` condition is never going to happen unless someone changes `BIG_BUFFER` to something stupidly low or if there's a bug in `snprintf()`, so it's impossible to cover that `if(...)` block in the tests. I suppose in this particular case I could replace that block with a carefully crafted static assert, but that's not always that simple. Is there a way to tell Sonar to ignore code coverage for these lines? I know about `// NOSONAR` but that's not only about coverage.

Comment: Can't you change `BIG_BUFFER` for something smaller in a test?

Comment: In this particular case BIG_BUFFER is actually PATH_MAX, so that would require an additional #define and make the code harder to read. And I as said I'm looking for a more general approach to this issue.

Comment: The general approach is that you mock as much as possible in tests to trigger certain conditions. You can also make `buf` global and redefine it in tests.

Comment: Sure, let me rephrase that then: with an existing code base, can I make SonarQube be quiet about specific non-covered blocks of code ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are one of the few new contributors who actually took the [tour]. Great! -- Would you mind to [edit] your question if you like to refine it? Comments are not viewed as part of a question (or answer). You might also like to add what you found so far, for example which documentation you have read, and what you have tried.